# Running multi-line bash script as string from C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, bash

I want to run following bash script from C++ code. I tries to use  `system()` or `popen` to run commands and capture its output but they but I get errors because built-in sh tries to execute it, such as,

```
sh: 6: [[: not found
sh: 8: [[: not found
sh: 9: [[: not found
```

I tried `bash -c` as well but that also produced errors because I think it doesn't handle multiline string.

I can't put below script in to .sh file and run it because of several reasons. So this script needs to be stored as a string in C++ code and get executed. Any idea how this can be done?

```
#!/bin/bash
for sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do
    (
        syspath="${sysdevpath%/dev}"
        devname="$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)"
        [[ "$devname" == "bus/"* ]] && continue
        eval "$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)"
        [[ -z "$ID_SERIAL" ]] && continue
        [[ "${ID_SERIAL}" == *"PX4"* ]] && echo "/dev/$devname"
    )
done
```

Sample code:

Note: You can use [this tool](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/cpp_text_escape.php?lang=en) to convert text to C++ escapped string.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << system("#!/bin/bash\nfor sysdevpath in $(find /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/ -name dev); do\n    (\n        syspath=\"${sysdevpath%/dev}\"\n        devname=\"$(udevadm info -q name -p $syspath)\"\n        [[ \"$devname\" == \"bus/\"* ]] && continue\n        eval \"$(udevadm info -q property --export -p $syspath)\"\n        [[ -z \"$ID_SERIAL\" ]] && continue\n        [[ \"${ID_SERIAL}\" == *\"PX4\"* ]] && echo \"/dev/$devname\"\n    )\ndone");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you put the script into an actual *file* that you then execute?

Comment: Why do you run the statements in a sub-shell with `(..)`?

Comment: The script would be run by library and I don't want to have extra .sh file getting shipped with library. Also, library would be used in Unreal engine build system which makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a multiline [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script to single-line. Let's assume you have the following [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script:

```
FOO=`uname`
if [ "$FOO" == "Linux" ]; then
    echo "You are using 'Linux'"
fi
```

The code above can be transformed into single-line by using **semicolons**:

```
FOO=`uname`; if [ "$FOO" == "Linux" ]; then echo "You are using 'Linux'"; fi
```

Now with proper escaping you can use `system` command to execute it from your [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) program as follows:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string foo {
        "bash -c '"
        "FOO=`uname`; "
        "if [ \"$FOO\" == \"Linux\" ]; then "
        "echo \"You are using 'Linux'.\"; "
        "fi'"
    };
    system(foo.c_str());
}
```

Note that adjacent string literals are concatenated by the compiler, so you can still make it look like a multiline script for better readability.

Comment: I'd tried similar approach but didn't worked before. In your answer key is to use single quotes for full command that avoids further problem with escapping the escapped string :). Also another small but fine detail is not to add ; after then.